# findAll() in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-cactiverecord

EmailArchive Table:

```
id email_id to from
1  101      uk  msm
2  102      uu  avc
3  101      rk  uk
4  103      xyz abc
5  104      xyz poi
6  104      abc xyz
7  101      xyz abc
```

Now in Yii I want record where email_id=101
I am using below code, but its not working.

```
$id =101;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition("email_id < :email_id");
$comments = EmailArchive::model()->findAll($criteria, array(':email_id' => $id,));
```

Answer (score 54):

Try:

```
$id =101;
$comments = EmailArchive::model()->findAll(
array("condition"=>"email_id =  $id","order"=>"id"));
```

OR

```
$id =101;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition("email_id=:email_id");
$criteria->params = array(':email_id' => $id);
$comments = EmailArchive::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

OR

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->condition = "email_id = $id";
$Products = Product::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you... you could mark the answer as Accepted...  )

Comment: why is no one using only find() not findAll() if its a single reccord , look at link for reference http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail i use something like this ;  $social = Social::model()->find(array(
            'having' => 'user_id=:user_id',
            'params' => array(
                ':user_id' => $user_id,
            )
                ));

Answer (score 7):

If you use `findAll()`, I recommend you to use this:

```
$data_email = EmailArchive::model()->findAll(
                  array(
                      'condition' => 'email_id = :email_id',
                      'params'    => array(':email_id' => $id)
                  )
              );
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to add some alternate, you could do like this also:

```
$id =101;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "email_id =:email_id";
$criteria->params = array(':email_id' => $id);
$comments = EmailArchive::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: $criteria->condition("email_id < :email_id"); condition is a property not a method

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way get by using findall in yii

```
$id =101; 
$comments = EmailArchive::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"':email_id'=$id"));
foreach($comments as $comments_1) 
{ 
echo  "email:".$comments_1['email_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your safest way to do it:

```
$id =101;
//$user_id=25;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition="email_id < :email_id";
//$criteria->addCondition("user_id=:user_id");
$criteria->params=array(
  ':email_id' => $id,
  //':user_id' => $user_id,
);
$comments=EmailArchive::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Note that if you comment out the commented lines you get a way to add more filtering to your search.

After this it is recommend to check if there is any data returned like:

```
if (isset($comments)) { // We found some comments, we can sleep well tonight
  // do comments process or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 101;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ur_tbl t WHERE t.email_id = '. $id;
$email = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

var_dump($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you user $criteria, I recommend blow usage:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('email_id', 101);
$comments = EmailArchive::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add some texts and explain what your code does and solve the question. In this way, more people will receive benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. This should work.

```
$comments = EmailArchive::find()->where(['email_id' => $id])->all();
```