# How to use where clause on the yii?

Tags: yii

I need to use where clause on `yii`, below of my code, I need to add `where activated == 0 && send_email == 0`.

```
$model = User::model()->findAll();
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736370/findall-in-yii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

```
$model = User::model()->findAll('activated=0 AND send_email=0');
```

Or,

```
$model = User::model()->findAll('activated=:activated And send_email=:sendEmail',
                                   array(':activated'=>0,':sendEmail'=> 0));
```

Or,

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;     
$criteria->condition='activated=:activated AND send_email=:sendEmail';
$criteria->params=array(':activated'=>0,':sendEmail'=>0);
$model=User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Or,

```
$model = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('activated'=>0, 'send_email'=>0));
```

Or,

```
$model = User::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM user WHERE activated=:activated AND send_email=:sendEmail', array(':activated'=>0, 'sendEmail'=>0));
```

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar). Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
$model = User::model()->findAll(array("condition"=> "activated=0 AND send_email=0"));
```