# how to use the search results of a query to search another table

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have the following code that searches a Table I have

```
$searchTax = new TaxonomySearch();
    $dataProviderTax = $searchTax->search(['TaxonomySearch'=>['tax_general'=>$spec]]);
```

how do I access the results of this search so I can use the results to search on another table?

```
$searchModel = new NpiSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['NpiSearch'=>['Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code'=>***results from dataProvidexTax***]]);
```

and display it all at once

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
[findAll() in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736370/findall-in-yii)

Additional method you might want to use:

```
$firstResults = results from findAll();
$fieldsToSearch = CHtml::listData($firstResults, 'fieldkeyselected', 'fieldvalueselected')
$additionalCondition = !empty($fieldsToSearch )?'field in ('.implode(',',$fieldsToSearch ).')':'';
... use findAll( $additionalCondition )
```